# Not able to import the another project as a library?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I am going to licensing my Application. I know all the process for licensing application.
But for that I have to load the Library Project in My Workspace.
I have loaded the Library Project in my WorkSpace then i have imported it into my Original project. It works great.

But now the problem is, If i have once deleted that library project and then if i have imported into workspace from another location and if i import it in to my that project then it is not going to import it.

And if i Import it from the previour one location, then its again works fine. . . 
So why it is happening like that?

Why i am not able to import the library project from any location?

Please guide me for this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know why it is happend. But if you have import once from any location. and then delete it.
Now if you are imported the same project from another location than it is also not going to imported.
For sollution you have to Put that library project at once place for which you what it every time.
And if necessary then do not delete that library project after Importing it to the Original Project.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this means your original project gets static path instead of local(folder inside application) path. And what about the uploading time, at that time it takes reference of library project on your machine?

Comment: It not taking the Static path as because While i m uploading it on to it takes whole project as the Working Project and take all the library included in it. But the same thing that iDroid face it also happend with me. And i have use that approach as i have explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, i am **assuming** that you want to import any library into your project and if you want to use any library(.jar) then you can do these steps:

1. create "libs" folder inside your application's structure, at same level of "src" directory.
2. Now copy those libraries into this libs folder.
3. Right click on any librarary -> Build Path -> Add to Build Path.

**Update**:
As you have commented below as its library project, i would suggest you to go through this Android doc on [Setting up a Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html)

Comment: No, Its not any Jar file. But its a Library Project. as like Facebooklibrary project for facebook integrayion or Licensing Library Project to Give Licensing to your android Project. Hope you got the point.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include a project to your current project follow the steps,

1.) `Right Click(or Alt+Enter)` on the `project_as_library->Library->` check mark `Is Library`

2.) `Right Click(or Alt+Enter)` on the project where you want to include the Library, go to `Android->Library->Add`. When you click `Add` you will see the `Project name` that you declared as `Library`, selected that and `Press Ok` and you are done.

Comment: I have already explained that i know all the steps to import other project as library in to another project. Please read my whole question and problem then answer me here. Thanks for reply.

Comment: If you are importing it from another workspace make sure that it does not still have another reference and make it as Library before adding it as Library for the Project.

Comment: Yes i have not any other reference of it but still i am not able to add it in to myMain Project. But if i add it from previous location then it can be Imported. Why it i happend like that ?

Comment: The project you want to add as Library is being created by you only or you have referenced it from somewhere?

Comment: No, Its a Licensing Project which use to give licensing to the Android Project. You can get it from your sdk diretory \android-sdk\extras\google\market_licensing\library    Here library is that Library project which is going to import in to another project.